# Mount command not working, pulling up info page on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I'm trying to mount one of my disks (/dev/sdb) to a particular user (/home/username), with "sudo mount ext2 /dev/sdb /home/username", and it doesn't look like it's working.  When I run that, it pulls up the exact same results as "mount -h", instead of mounting the disk.  I've also tried "sudo mount -t ext2 /dev/sdb /home/username", and that doesn't work either.  (When I run lsblk, it doesn't have a mountpoint for sdb.)  I don't think I have the syntax wrong, but I might.

Comment: is `/home/username` an empty directory?

Comment: It is not an empty directory, no.  It mainly has some .zip files in it, though, which can be deleted at any time.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, though, since it would just "overmount" if anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to the question after a while, but rather than deleting my question I figured I'd answer it if anyone else had a similar problem.

The drive I was trying to mount didn't have a filesystem attached to it, once I ran fdisk and partitioned it (it's ext4 now), I could mount the partition without a problem.